# Do I need to update my path to run ts-node on iterm (zsh)?

Tags: typescript, settings, zsh, iterm, ts-node

I tried installing ts-node using npm using the following commands,

```
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g ts-node
```

reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#installation

However, when I run the ts-node on my terminal,
I get such error: **zsh: command not found: ts-node**

FYI, `echo $PATH`  produces
`/Users/myname/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myname/Desktop/flutter/flutter/bin:/Users/myname/Desktop/flutter/flutter/bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin`

Please help and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm bin -g` to get the global [npm bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-bin) directory and then add it to `PATH`.

Comment: I forgot to comment at that time but it helped so much!!! Thank you so much!!